# Drumgizmo midi drum plugin with Ardour

Tags: software-installation, music, plugins, ardour

Trying to install DrumGizmo (Midi Drum Plugin) as an LV2 Plugin for Ardour.

Update: Ok, DrumGizmo seems to be a **part of the Ubuntu Packages**.

Running a package search on packages.ubuntu.com returns:

- xenial (sound): Audio sampler plugin and stand-alone app that
  simulates a real drum kit [universe] 0.9.8.1-3: amd64 arm64 armhf
  i386 powerpc ppc64el s390x
- yakkety (sound): Audio sampler plugin and
  stand-alone app that simulates a real drum kit [universe] 0.9.10-1:
  amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el s390x

Now, I have "Trusty" installed on top of Ubuntu Studio. Can I **add the DrumGizmo package anyway**?

---

On a previous install attempt I've been following this description:
http://www.drumgizmo.org/wiki/doku.php?id=documentation:compiling_installing_-_linux

Now, when I launch Ardour and try to add the plugin I get an error message
[image]

Any suggestions for info I need to supply to solve this problem are welcome. Thanks!

---

**Further Details**

- The source file is drumgizmo-0.9.10.tar.gz
- Ardour 3.5.403~dfsg-3~ubuntu14 (built from revision 3.5.403~dfsg-3~ubuntu14.04.1)
- Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

There was an error message during install ...

```
gemini@greyshark:/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry  $ make install
Making install in plugingui
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/plugingui'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/plugingui'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/plugingui'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/plugingui'
Making install in tools
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/tools'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/tools'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/tools'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/tools'
Making install in include
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/include'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/include'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/include'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/include'
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/src'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/src'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/src'
Making install in plugin
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/plugin'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/plugin'
make  install-exec-hook
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/plugin'
rm -f /home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/install/lib/lv2/drumgizmo.lv2/drumgizmo.la
rm -f /home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/install/lib/vst/drumgizmo_vst.la
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/plugin'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/install/lib/lv2/drumgizmo.lv2'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 manifest.ttl drumgizmo.ttl '/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/install/lib/lv2/drumgizmo.lv2'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/install/lib/lv2/drumgizmo.lv2'
 /bin/bash ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   drumgizmo.la '/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/install/lib/lv2/drumgizmo.lv2'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/drumgizmo.so /home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/install/lib/lv2/drumgizmo.lv2/drumgizmo.so
/usr/bin/install: target 'Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/install/lib/lv2/drumgizmo.lv2/drumgizmo.so' is not a directory
make[2]: *** [install-lv2pluginLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/plugin'
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/gemini/Desktop/Files/Media/Music Composition/20160913-Temp Setup Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/plugin'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**This issue is due to** spaces in the directory path. Here in this error message you can see that the path before *Guitar/Tom-Input/...* is cut off because of the space before it.

```
/usr/bin/install: target 'Guitar/Tom-Input/drumgizmo_2ndtry/install/lib/lv2/drumgizmo.lv2/drumgizmo.so' is not a directory
```

**To fix this**, store, build, and install the tarball from a directory that doesn't contain any spaces in the directory path.

The limitation that the directory path cannot contain spaces comes from libtool and unfortunately they also won't fix this issue.